# MSAccess calling MSWord

Tags: ms-access, dialog, mailmerge

I have an MSAccess database that uses docmd to open a word document that calls a mail merge. Everything works fine except there is a dialog box that it hidden from the user. Alt Tab must be used to call the dialog box to the screen.

Is there a means of bringing that dialog box to the fore front?

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact DoCmd-command? Maybe you start an external application? After that you don't have control of it. It's better to use it this way:

First make a reference to your version of Office (in **VBA-editor**: menu **Tools** > **References**) select:

> **Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library**

Then in VBA use this code:

```
'Create Word object (open Word)
Dim WordApp As Object
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'Mailmerge
WordApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
WordApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
    GetCSVFileName(aSurvey, ModuleName), _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
    WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", SQLStatement1 _
    :="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther
```

And at the end, close:

```
WordApp.Quit 0
Set WordApp = Nothing
```

You can get the specific code by recording a macro (in Word) while performing the mailmerge. This way you can do all kinds of things with Word: open document, start mailmerge, save to PDF, etc. All from within your Access VBA. This way, I think, there is need to respond to pop-up's, because all is handled in code.